# MacBook Pro crashes when plugging in external HD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, crash, kernel-panic

Every time I plug my WD My Book Duo, my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, MacOS 13.6.1 (22G313)) crashes. I don't think there's an issue with the WD tower; I think there's something wrong with the HDD because when I swap out the HDD for another, I'm able to read the new HDD.

I've got the software to try and recover some data from the HDD, but I can't even try since my MacBook crashes the moment I plug in the WD tower — I couldn't even try to format the HDD. What are my options here. In addition to booting in safe mode, I've tried plugging in the HDD to a Windows PC. It won't read the HDD.

Copied is the report that's generated when the MacBook crashes:

```
*** MCA Error Report ***
CPU Machine Check Architecture Error Dump (CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz, CPUID: 0x806E9)
CATERR detected! No MCA data found.


panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8009ad74e3): "jnl: do_jnl_io: curlen == 0, offset 0x4b7000 len 0\n" @hfs_journal.c:354
Panicked task 0xffffff99c1b02258: 1 threads: pid 960: mount_hfs
Backtrace (CPU 0), panicked thread: 0xffffff902a415598, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffba9bf77260 : 0xffffff8008070c7d 
0xffffffba9bf772b0 : 0xffffff80081c4f54 
0xffffffba9bf772f0 : 0xffffff80081b4a67 
0xffffffba9bf77340 : 0xffffff8008011971 
0xffffffba9bf77360 : 0xffffff8008070f5d 
0xffffffba9bf77450 : 0xffffff8008070607 
0xffffffba9bf774b0 : 0xffffff80087db9ab 
0xffffffba9bf775a0 : 0xffffff8009ad74e3 
0xffffffba9bf77610 : 0xffffff8009ad85c6 
0xffffffba9bf77730 : 0xffffff8009ad7d64 
0xffffffba9bf777c0 : 0xffffff8009b0fa32 
0xffffffba9bf77890 : 0xffffff8009afcddf 
0xffffffba9bf779d0 : 0xffffff8009af597a 
0xffffffba9bf77a70 : 0xffffff8008249fe5 
0xffffffba9bf77cb0 : 0xffffff800824b728 
0xffffffba9bf77f00 : 0xffffff800824b13e 
0xffffffba9bf77f40 : 0xffffff800865b300 
0xffffffba9bf77fa0 : 0xffffff8008011db6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext(627.100.6)[954A1920-BCF6-3E96-A1DF-4121B091D900]@0xffffff8009ac3000->0xffffff8009b21fff
            dependency: com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext(1)[99FC46C3-46A0-3D82-B6F8-226352685442]@0xffffff8009b28000->0xffffff8009b29fff

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff902a415598): mount_hfs

Mac OS version:
22G313

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Wed Oct  4 21:25:26 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3.701.17~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 6059599F-7994-349C-8DC6-03F3B60C83DE
roots installed: 0
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000007c00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8007e00000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000007cdc000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8007edc000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007d00000
System model name: MacBookPro14,1 (Mac-B4831CEBD52A0C4C)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 561090322260
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00000082a396e29c
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000c9a98955a 0x0000000000000000
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff8028c39000 - 0xffffffa028c39000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff8028c39000 - 0xffffff8029c3a000
  . VM    : 0xffffff8029c3a000 - 0xffffff84f66a0000
  . RO    : 0xffffff84f66a0000 - 0xffffff868ff6c000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff868ff6c000 - 0xffffff8b5c9d2000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff8b5c9d2000 - 0xffffff9029438000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffff9029438000 - 0xffffff94f5e9e000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffff94f5e9e000 - 0xffffff99c2905000
  . DATA  : 0xffffff99c2905000 - 0xffffffa028c39000
  Metadata: 0xffffffa06c338000 - 0xffffffa08c338000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffa08c338000 - 0xffffffa08db38000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

last started kext at 27741215048: com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs 82.1.16 (addr 0xffffff7f9edeb000, size 262144)
loaded kexts:
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   82.1.16
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   131
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  440.2
>!AHDA  440.2
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 7.1.18
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>eficheck   1
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   7.1.18
>pmtelemetry    1
@filesystems.nfs    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    20.0.6
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!AGFXHDA   240.1
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 20.0.6
>AGDCBacklightControl   7.1.18
@UVCService 1
>!ABacklight    180.8
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  198.100.13
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.16
>!ACameraInterface  7.13.0
|SCSITaskUserClient 482.120.2
>!UMass!SInterfaceNub   554
>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   627.100.6
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    6440.7
@filesystems.apfs   2142.140.9
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AUserConsent  1
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    404
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.Compression    1
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>DspFuncLib 440.2
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 530
>!AGraphicsControl  7.1.18
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
@kext.triggers  1.0
>IOHIDPowerSource   1
>!ACallbackPowerSource  1
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1140.6
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    560.2
>!AAudioClockLibs   240.1
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
>!AHDA!C    440.2
|IOHDA!F    440.2
|IOAudio!F  440.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1150.2
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOAccelerator!F2   475.40.6
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  597
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!ARSMChannel   1
|IORSM!F    1
>!AIPAppender   1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  7.1.18
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    7.1.18
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IOGraphics!F   597
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter  4.1.1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  336.60.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ASyntheticGame!C  10.7.1
>!AActuatorDriver   6440.7
>!AHIDKeyboard  231
>!AMultitouchDriver 6440.7
>!AInputDeviceSupport   6460.1
>!AHS!BDriver   6440.7
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   63
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AHSSPISupport 63
|IO80211!FLegacy    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1150.2
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  554
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  235.140.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  482.120.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  482.120.2
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACyrus    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   5.0.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0


*** Device Tree ***
{
    "pcie_cfg_base" : "0xe0000000",
    "pci_devices" :
    {
        "0x0" : "MCHC@0",
        "0x10000" : "IGPU@2",
        "0xa0000" : "XHC1@14",
        "0xaa000" : "pci8086,9d62@15,2",
        "0xa8000" : "pci8086,9d60@15",
        "0xb0000" : "IMEI@16",
        "0xe0000" : "RP01@1C",
        "0xe4000" : "RP05@1C,4",
        "0xe8000" : "RP09@1D",
        "0xf0000" : "URT0@1E",
        "0xe9000" : "RP10@1D,1",
        "0xf3000" : "SPI1@1E,3",
        "0xf8000" : "LPCB@1F",
        "0xfb000" : "HDEF@1F,3",
        "0xfa000" : "PMCR@1F,2",
        "0xfc000" : "SBUS@1F,4",
        "0x100000" : "RP01@1C/IOPP/SSD0@0",
        "0x400000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0",
        "0x300000" : "RP10@1D,1/IOPP/CMRA@0",
        "0x200000" : "RP09@1D/IOPP/ARPT@0",
        "0x500000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0",
        "0x508000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1",
        "0x510000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2",
        "0x520000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB4@4",
        "0x700000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0",
        "0x8300000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1/IOPP/UPS0@0",
        "0x600000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC2@0",
        "0x8410000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1/IOPP/UPS0@0/IOPP/pci-bridge@2",
        "0x8420000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1/IOPP/UPS0@0/IOPP/pci-bridge@4",
        "0x8500000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1/IOPP/UPS0@0/IOPP/pci-bridge@2/IOPP/pci8086,15f0@0"
    },
    "device_mmio" :
    {
        "PCI0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xcf8", "s" : "0x8" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IGPU@2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4020000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },
            { "a" : "0x4010000000", "s" : "0x10000000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4021010000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/pci8086,9d60@15" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4021028000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/pci8086,9d62@15,2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4021027000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IMEI@16" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4021026000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP01@1C/IOPP/SSD0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x92700000", "s" : "0x4000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x92a00000", "s" : "0x40000" },
            { "a" : "0x92a40000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1/IOPP/UPS0@0/IOPP/pci-bridge@2/IOPP/pci8086,15f0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x92b00000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC2@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x92900000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP09@1D/IOPP/ARPT@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x92400000", "s" : "0x8000" },
            { "a" : "0x92000000", "s" : "0x400000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP10@1D,1/IOPP/CMRA@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x92600000", "s" : "0x10000" },
            { "a" : "0x4000000000", "s" : "0x10000000" },
            { "a" : "0x92500000", "s" : "0x100000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/URT0@1E" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4021025000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SPI1@1E,3" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4021024000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PMCR@1F,2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x92824000", "s" : "0x4000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/HDEF@1F,3" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4021020000", "s" : "0x4000" },
            { "a" : "0x4021000000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SBUS@1F,4" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4021029000", "s" : "0x100" }
        ],
        "DMAC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x0", "s" : "0x20" },
            { "a" : "0x81", "s" : "0x11" },
            { "a" : "0x93", "s" : "0xd" },
            { "a" : "0xc0", "s" : "0x20" }
        ],
        "FWHD" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xff000000", "s" : "0x1000000" }
        ],
        "IPIC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x20", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x24", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x28", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x2c", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x30", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x34", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x38", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x3c", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa0", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa4", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa8", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xac", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb0", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb4", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb8", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xbc", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x4d0", "s" : "0x2" }
        ],
        "MATH" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xf0", "s" : "0x1" }
        ],
        "LDRC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x2e", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x4e", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x61", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x63", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x65", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x67", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x80", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x92", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0xb2", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xffff", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x1800", "s" : "0xff" },
            { "a" : "0x800", "s" : "0x80" }
        ],
        "RTC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x70", "s" : "0x8" }
        ],
        "TIMR" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x40", "s" : "0x4" },
            { "a" : "0x50", "s" : "0x4" }
        ],
        "SMC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x300", "s" : "0x20" },
            { "a" : "0xfef00000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "EC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x62", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x66", "s" : "0x1" }
        ],
        "PDRC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xfed10000", "s" : "0x8000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed18000", "s" : "0x1000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed19000", "s" : "0x1000" },
            { "a" : "0xe0000000", "s" : "0x10000000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed20000", "s" : "0x20000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed90000", "s" : "0x4000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed45000", "s" : "0x4b000" },
            { "a" : "0xff000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },
            { "a" : "0xfee00000", "s" : "0x100000" },
            { "a" : "0xfd000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe000000", "s" : "0x10000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe010000", "s" : "0x1000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe020000", "s" : "0x16000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe036000", "s" : "0x6000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe03c000", "s" : "0x1000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe03d000", "s" : "0x83000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe0c0000", "s" : "0x40000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe100000", "s" : "0x100000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe200000", "s" : "0x200000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe400000", "s" : "0x10000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe410000", "s" : "0x1f0000" },
            { "a" : "0xfe600000", "s" : "0x200000" }
        ],
        "MEM2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x20000000", "s" : "0x200000" },
            { "a" : "0x40000000", "s" : "0x200000" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tetsujin the last loaded KEXT is, in the general case, not causatively linked to the actual source of a panic or hang (although sometimes there is correlation because of timing). If you examine the panic report, the backtrace indicates that (1) the caller of the `panic()` subroutine was located in the memory map of the HFS+ driver, (2) the active process was the `mount_hfs` command which runs via the automount mechanism whenever an HFS+ drive is attached, and (3) the actual panic reason given was due a corrupt HFS+ journal entry, which is first accessed upon an HFS+ volume mount.

Answer (score 0):

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8009ad74e3): "jnl: do_jnl_io: curlen == 0, offset 0x4b7000 len 0\n" @hfs_journal.c:354
```

This is a synchronous panic in the HFS+ filesystem driver. It expressly indicates filesystem corruption. You need to use a tool like [**DiskWarrior**](https://www.alsoft.com) to attempt to repair the corruption.

Comment: @Tetsujin When the DiskWarrior app is running, it installs a filesystem event hook to intercept volume mounts in order to prevent exactly this scenario.